# What is this Facebook permission field: "friends_permission"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

There is a separate column for what is la labeled as "friends_permission". What is this and what does it all *mean*?

Answer (score 1):

This means you can get not only permission for some user data but also for friends of that user. Not all data is available though.

Example:

If you get user 123 to allow the `user_about_me` permission it means you can get his/her about_me information.

If you get the same 123 user to allow the `friends_about_me` permission then you can get all of his/her friends about_me info